# SharePoint Workflow Subscription Service failed

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, undefined, sharepoint-workflow

I have one requirement to start the SP workflow through JavaScript. For this, i have wrote some lines of code to start the workflow.But I am getting a Subscription failed error due to undefined object. This is occuring at ExcecuteasyncQuery method. So i didn't get which object returns the undefined value. My code is shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.workflowservices.js">      </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var subID = "3debdbad-db52-4586-87e1-40e4db581da5";

function GetCurrentItemID()
{
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);

for (item in selectedItems)
{
var itemId = selectedItems[item].id;
startWorkflow(itemId, subID);
}
}

function startWorkflow(itemID, subID) {    
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
 var wfServiceManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(context, web);
var subscription = wfServiceManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().getSubscription(subID);

context.load(subscription);

context.executeQueryAsync(
    function(sender, args){
        alert("Subscription load success. Attempting to start workflow.");        
        var inputParameters = {};
        wfServiceManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflowOnListItem
        (subscription, itemID, inputParameters);

        context.executeQueryAsync(
            function(sender, args){ alert("Successfully starting workflow."); },
            function(sender, args){ 
                alert("Failed to start workflow.");
                alert("Error: " + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
            }
        );
    },
    function(sender,args){
        alert("Failed to load subscription.");
        alert("Error: " + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
);
}
</script>
```

I am calling the GetCurrentItemID() function at the button click. But at that time, i am getting the following error.

> Failed to load subscription
>
> Invalid Request
>
> Undefined

Could any one please help me to sort out this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

According to the script and the error message,

I suggest you check whether the “subscription” and “itemId” objects hold the proper values.

What’s more, you can take a look at the two links below about how to start workflow using JavaScript Client Object Model:

http://usamawahabkhan.blogspot.com/2013/07/start-workflow-sharepoint-2010.html

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87015/solved-start-a-workflow-of-the-host-web-via-sharepoint-app-and-jsom

Feel free to reply with the test result or if there are any progress.

Comment: The itemId and is returns correct value and subscription return non null value.

Comment: ill get back to you. i am looking in this matter .

Comment: can we have do Skype text?

Comment: Hi, Have you got any solution on this? i am still struggling on this. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: No i am still working on this, i can't get any reliable point for this. I'll get back to u . Let's Do continue in chat .

Comment: "nisam.bahamed" Please add me in skype.

Comment: Wait. i ll share my ID .

Answer (score 0):

Building on the solutions provided by others, here's the code I was able to use.  NOTE: You need to have your workflow set to "Allow this workflow to be started manually."

```
/**
*   Starts a SharePoint 2013 Workflow on a particular list item.
*   Params:
*       workflowName: The name of the Workflow
*       listGUID: the GUID of the list
*       itemId: the ID of the list item
*/  
function startListWorkflow(workflowName, listGUID, itemId){
    SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext" , function(){
        SP.SOD.registerSod('sp.workflowservices.js', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.workflowservices.js'));
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.workflowservices.js', "SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager", 
            function(){
                var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(),
                wfsManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(ctx, ctx.get_web()),
                wfSubs = wfsManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().enumerateSubscriptionsByList(listGUID);
                ctx.load(wfSubs);
                ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                    wfsEnum = wfSubs.getEnumerator();
                    while (wfsEnum.moveNext()) {
                        var wfSub = wfsEnum.get_current();
                        if (wfSub.get_name() === workflowName) {
                            var initiationParams = {}; 
                            wfsManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflowOnListItem(wfSub, itemId, initiationParams);
                            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                               function (sender, args) {
                                    console.log("Successfully started workflow.");
                               },
                               function (sender, args) {
                                    console.log("Failed to start the workflow.");
                                    console.log("Error: " + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
                               }
                           );
                        }
                    }
                },function(e){
                    console.error(e)
                });
            }
        );
    });         
}
```